# SonarQube scanning a scala Project

Tags: scala, sonarqube

Is there a plugin for SonarQube 5.6.6 to scan a Scala project?

And can I exclude FindBugs for a project?

Comment: There is currently no language plugin for scala listed in the official plugin repository: http://www.sonarplugins.com/search.html?query=scala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Other Plugins page](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Other+Plugins) lists the [Scalastyle Plugin](https://github.com/emrehan/sonar-scalastyle). Google may find additional plugins.

Since this plugin is on the Other Plugins page, it means that it's not in the update center, so you'll have to install it manually if you want to use it:

- download plugin
- drop plugin in *$SONARQUBE_HOME/extensions/plugins*
- restart the server

If I were you, I'd `tail -f` the *$SONARQUBE_HOME/logs/sonar.log* just to make sure the server starts back up without error.

Comment: does this one also run with SonarQube 5.6.6

Comment: no idea @Felix. That's one reason I advise watching the logs at startup.